# Downloading directory from FTP server

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, c++builder-xe5

I am developing FTP client by RAD Studio (`IdFTP`). How I can dowload directory from server?
Delphi or C++. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, what failed? Googling "idftp directory list" gives you enough to start.

Comment: I can get list. But i need download folders with files. Procedure get() - donwload a file from server. I do not understand how download all files. Folder may contain other folders and files...

Comment: That's a repeated get() while traversing through the directories. Google it, start building, place your code here when it fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745994/how-to-download-file-using-tidftp-in-delphixe2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `TIdFTP.ChangeDir()` to go to the desired starting directory, then call `TIdFTP.List()` to retrieve the names of its files and subdirectories, then loop through the `TIdFTP.DirectoryListing` calling `TIdFTP.Get()` on each filename and store each subdirectory name into your own local list, then finally repeat the above steps on each subdirectory in your local list.

For example:

```
Procedure DownloadFolder(ARemoteFolder, ALocalFolder: string);
Var
  SubFolders: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
Begin
  ALocalFolder := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ALocalFolder);
  ForceDirectories(ALocalFolder);
  SubFolders := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    FTP.ChangeDir(ARemoteFolder);
    FTP.List;
    For I := 0 to FTP.DirectoryListing.Count-1 do
    Begin
      If FTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType = ditFile then
      Begin
        FTP.Get(FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName, ALocalFolder + FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName);
      End
      Else if FTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType = ditDirectory then
      Begin
        if (FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName <> '.') and FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName <> '..') then
          SubFolders.Add(FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName);
      End;     
    End;
    For I := 0 to SubFolders.Count-1 do
    Begin
      DownloadFolder(ARemoteFolder + '/' + SubFolders[I], ALocalFolder + SubFolders[I]);
    End;
  Finally
    SubFolders.Free;
  End;
End;
```

```
DownloadFolder('/StartingDir', 'C:\Downloaded');
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that there must be recursion. Could you show me how I can get around all the directories and subdirectories?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. May need some tweaking, but it will give you the jist of it.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to add the condition:

> Else if ((IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType = ditDirectory) and
>   **(Length(IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName) > 2)**) then

to avoid ".." as the directory name

Comment: Relying on the Length like that is wrong as there could be real folders with only 1-2 characters in them. To ignore the `".."` item, check for that specifically, and for good measure look for `"."`, too, eg: `Else if ((IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType = ditDirectory) and (IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName <> '.') and (IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName <> '..')) then`