# Downloading directory from FTP server with Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, ftp

i used [this codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154498/downloading-directory-from-ftp-server), but i am taking' "xxx.xxx" not understood' error message sometimes. And it doesn't download and than i am taking "unable to build data connection: connection time out" message.

My ConnectionTimeOut setting is 240000.

What can i do? Can you help me please? I am using Delphi XE.

Have nice day.

Comment: The code you refer to doesn't include instantiating `ftp` nor setting it up for connection. Please show that code as it appears your code doesn't connect.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to include your own code to solve your problem.but,To download my file,
I zip the file or folder on the server and then receive the following code in the client:

```
var
  STListZip: TStringList;
  SZipDown: String;
  fFtp:TIdFTP;
begin
  fFtp := TIdFTP.Create(nil);

  fFtp.Passive := true;
  fFtp.Host := 'myserver.com';
  fFtp.Username := 'u1';
  fFtp.Password := '1';
  fFtp.port:='21';
  fFtp.ConnectTimeout := 20000;
  fFtp.TransferTimeout := 20000;
  try
    fFtp.Connect;
    fFtp.ChangeDir('');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('ERROR ftp not connect');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  if fFtp.Connected then
  begin
    STListZip := TStringList.Create;
    fFtp.List(STListZip, 'abc.zip', false);
    if STListZip.Count < 1 then
    begin
      ShowMessage('ERROR file not exist');
      Exit;
    end;
    STListZip.Sort;
    SZipDown := STListZip[STListZip.Count - 1];
    try
        fftp.BeginWork(wmRead);
        fftp.Get(SZipDown, 'd:\', true, fftp.ResumeSupported);
        fftp.Disconnect();
        fftp.EndWork(wmRead);
    except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage('ERROR File not download');
          Exit;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Notice: Instead of `abc.zip` you can put `*.zip` to get all the zip file names.