# Delphi IdFTP: how to check type of file entry?

Tags: delphi, indy

I actually did this

```
FTP.Connect;
FTP.Login;
FTP.List;
StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := 'Connessione FTP riuscita';
For I := 0 to FTP.DirectoryListing.Count - 1 do
begin


  if (FTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType <> ditFile) then continue;

  lstFTPFiles.Items.Add(FTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName + #9        )
end;
```

Note the line

```
if (FTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType <> ditFile) then continue;
```

I atually get the error

> E2003: Undelcared identifier: ditFile

I see this syntax here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23158116/1055279

Should I `use` or declare something to be able to use this constant?

Comment: it'd seem you are missing a use, perhaps `IdFTPList` where `ditFile` (part of TIdDirItemType) is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended doing this (as suggested from [@istepaniuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888525/istepaniuk)).

> I learned also how to follow unit code in the IDE to try the unit to import and find type declarations

1. Added this to the `uses` list

   ```
   IdFTPList
   ```
2. Changed the line as

   ```
   if (FTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType <> TIdDirItemType.ditFile)
   ```

I don't know if there is a more idiomatic and short way to perform same task.

Comment: Adding/using/importing packages/units/modules/libraries is basic knowledge to programming - not everything is magically available. You really didn't wonder why Pascal has its 'uses' section so far? Also: are you sure your quotation formatting is intended?

Comment: Today is litterally the 2nd day in Delphi. I am facing a very smal issue in a old software of a fired coworker. So .. no time for a course, we are Googling and readings docs and trying .... and asking. We are php developers, be patient.