# Simple Delphi Firemonkey TidFTP test download hangs at 'Starting FTP transfer'

Tags: delphi, ftp, firemonkey, indy

I'm making a simple FTP download test with TidFTP using a Multi-device application in Delphi XE7. My objective is later to see this working in Android before using this functionality in my App but for now, I'm running this test in Windows 32-bit. The problem is that my FTP status text (as shown by a memo) 'resolves host', 'connects', 'establishes connection', and then 'Starts FTP transfer' but hangs there never returning from Get until a 'read timeout'. The first time this pops up a firewall warning which I accept but retries do the same thing. I've downloaded and built the [Indy FTP client demo](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/index.EN.aspx) which runs but does exactly the same thing.

I'm running in a virtual machine so I've tried running my EXE's (demo and my simple project) on the host machine and I get the same problem, however 'WinSCP' the FTP tool works fine with the same logon and port 21 allowing me to see my source file.

Here's my code cribbed largely from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745994/how-to-download-file-using-tidftp-in-delphixe2) to fetch a small text file in the root of my website:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := 'www.mysite.co.uk';
  IdFTP1.Username := 'username';
  IdFTP1.Password := 'password';
  IdFtp1.Passive := false;
  IdFtp1.ConnectTimeout := 1000;
  IdFtp1.Connect();
  IdFtp1.BeginWork(wmRead);
  IdFTP1.ChangeDir( '/' );
  IdFTP1.Get( 'hope.txt', 'c:\scratch\wow.txt', True );
  IdFtp1.Disconnect();
end;

procedure TForm4.IdFTP1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add( AStatusText );
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

I'm not proud of Application.ProcessMessages but I will replace it later with a thread and in any case there seems to be no 'TidAntiFreeze' in the Android framework (although the same code placed into a VCL application form with a TidAntiFreeze behaved the same too).

Any comments gratefully received.

Comment: Are you sure that Passive mode must be disabled? (Did you try `Passive := True`?)

Comment: I'm not sure but IdFTP1Status is fired from another thread(non VCL one). There may be race conditions when the progress of download begin...Check this first.

Comment: @mjn: Thanks, passive did need to be true, not false. In ignorance I must have just copied that and not tweaked it. Thank you, I'm off to read about what 'passive' actually does.

Comment: @iPathツ IIRC Delphi event handlers should be called from the main (VCL) thread. The Indy Telnet client for example, which uses a background thread, always synchronizes method calls with the main thread. The only exceptions I know are server components such as the Indy TCP server.

Comment: @iPath: `TIdFTP` is not a multi-threaded component. It runs in whatever thread context is using it. That means the `OnStatus` event is also fired in that same thread context. As for `TIdTelnet`, it has a `ThreadedEvent` property that controls whether its events are fired in the main thread or not.

Comment: @BrianFrost: FTP uses separate sockets for data transfers. `TIdFTP.Passive` tells the FTP server whether data connections are active or passive. When `Passive` is true (passive mode), the FTP server opens a listening socket that `TIdFTP` connects to for each transfer. When `Passive` is false (active mode), `TIdFTP` opens a listening socket that the FTP server connects to for each transfer. Passive mode transfers are more friendly to client-side firewalls/routers since they are outbound connections. Active mode transfers require a firewall to open ports, and a router to enable port forwarding.